# ASM imul confusion

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm looking at some assembly code for multiplication and am a bit stumped on the output.

```
move eax, ecx
imul edx
```

where `ecx` is 20336 and `edx` is 1321528399.

The value being returned when i view `edx` after executing the instruction is 6257, which doesn't make much sense to me.

These are very large numbers, so i figured its likely overflowing -- but i tried applying a mask and didn't arrive at the expected result.

Any clue on how this product can be derived?

Comment: `(20336 * 1321528399) >> 32 = 6257`, the expected result for the high-half of the 32x32 => 64-bit multiply result in EDX:EAX.  One-operand `imul` can't overflow the full result, only the low half (i.e. `cdq` would change EDX instead of setting it to the value it already had).

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes. I'm a n00b, how would i find the lower half?

Comment: See the linked duplicate and my first comment.  And read the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul.  BTW, if you only want the low half in the first place, do `imul esi, edi` or whatever instead of using the slow one-operand form of `imul` that has to produce both.

Comment: @Hysii What does eax contain afterwards?